# Is paging in DataGridView possible?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Is paging in DataGridView possible in VB.NET? 
I've successfully connected to a database and is able to import the data into the DataGrid, but the problem is that the table i have is huge with over 10mil rows. So showing in all in one view is either slowing down the loading time, or if i choose to add more columns of data the application will turn out to be an error.

For example, this line would work

`cmd.CommandText = "SELECT primaryTitle, startYear, runtimeMinutes, genres, FROM Basics"`

but this line would throw me an error called System.OutOfMemoryException

`cmd.CommandText = "SELECT primaryTitle, startYear, runtimeMinutes, genres, directors, writers FROM Basics, Crew"`

Any help would be appreciated.

This is my current code. The only thing i've done is importing the data into the DataGridView, nothing more since i can't proceed anymore.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-7SOUE1N\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=IMDb MOVIE DATABASE SYSTEM;Integrated Security=True"
        con.Open()

        Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT primaryTitle, startYear, runtimeMinutes, genres, directors, writers FROM Basics, Crew"
        Dim rdr As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Load(rdr)
        rdr.Close()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

        con.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Is importing it to a datatable to manage it an option, or do you need to do it at the SQL level?

Comment: Importing it to a datagridview is not an option, the question requires me to list everything in a table and column view upon startup.

Comment: You may want to have a look at [VirtualMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/virtual-mode-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, certainly is. This is how I usually do it.

Prerequisities:

- `DataGridView` DataGridView1
- `ToolStrip` ToolStrip1

  - `TextBox` PageNo
  - `Label` PageCount
  - `Button` btnPageBack
  - `Button` btnPageNext
  - `Label` TotalShown
  - `Label` OutOfTotalRecords
  - (some labels like "Page", " from ", "Total shown ", " out of ", " records")
- Dim RowsPerPage as Int16 = 40     ' set

This is how the `ToolStrip` bellow `DataGridView` footer looks in designer:

[image]

Fetching or updating the list SQL (wrapped in `LoadListOfRecords()` sub):

```
"SELECT
    ...
 ORDER BY " & dgwSortCol & " " & dgwSortOrder & "  " &
 OFFSET " & ((IIf(Me.PageNo.Text = "", 1, CInt(Me.PageNo.Text)) - 1) * RowsPerPage) & " 
 ROWS FETCH NEXT " & RowsPerPage & " ROWS ONLY; "
```

You might skip `ORDER` at first. But notice `OFFSET xx ROWS`, which tells where in database it should start to read records (by how many records to offset it from beginning) and `FETCH NEXT xx ROWS ONLY`, which tells how many rows to read and load to a "page". I skipped stuff like creating `DataSet`, reading `DataTable`, assigning it to `DataGridView`'s `DataSource` and such.

Button Back (I won't put Next, it's nearly identical, just changed limiting condition and iteration):

```
Private Sub btnPageBack_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPageBack.Click
    If CInt(Me.PageNo.Text) > 1 Then
        Me.PageNo.Text = CInt(Me.PageNo.Text) - 1
    End If
    Call LoadListOfRecords()
End Sub
```

Manual entry of page number (go to particular page), following `Enter` key stroke:

```
Private Sub PageNo_KeyDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles PageNo.KeyDown
    Call LoadListOfRecords()
End Sub
```

And that's about it. Simple, easy to use by users, works as charm, proven by time. No clutter of 3rd party controls and libraries.

Comment: `SELECT primaryTitle, startYear, runtimeMinutes, genres FROM Basics 
ORDER BY primaryTitle ASC 
OFFSET ((IIf(Me.PageNo.Text = "", 1, CInt(Me.PageNo.Text)) - 1) * 50) 
FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY"`

Is this wrong? My code cant seem to work

Comment: Yep, there's a little mistake in your SQL code, notice you're missing `ROWS` next to the code in brackets. So it's like `OFFSET 500 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY`. It's good to troubleshoot the SQL code in tools like SSMS and then use it in your VB.NET code.